# c++ "cout << number" results with printing "number%" to the screen

Tags: c++, int, cout

I have a strange problem, simple program, f.e.

```
main()
{
    int i=1;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Results with

```
1%
```

on screen. I can't get rid of that "%". Does anyone know what is going on? I am using g++ (GCC) 4.8.0 20130502 on Arch Linux.

Comment: That's not real C++. Functions have to have return types.

Comment: what happens if you add `<<"\n";` to the second line? is "%" a part of your prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The '%' is not from the program - It is from the shell that you are running it from.

Try

```
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: (Removed the `;` in the middle of the statement)

Comment: @WayneUroda - just curious - why a +1 for `endl`?

Comment: @user93353 - People tend to forget!

Comment: We all have a "senior" moment once in a while!

Comment: @user93353 I thought I knew (I thought it was "more correct" C++, also I thought it was more platform aware [linux uses \n for line endings, windows uses \r\n, some older crazy systems used \r...]) but after looking into it now, I'm not so sure. In this case it flushes the `cout` stream immediately whereas `'\n'` or `"\n"` doesn't. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @WayneUroda - I know - that's why I asked. endl isn't more correct or more platform aware.

Comment: @user93353 well as they say, 'you learn something new every day", so thanks for pointing that out. Still, I think I would prefer endl in my own code, just a style choice more than anything (unless there was some performance critical aspect).

Answer (score 2):

Is the `%` your shell prompt?

If so, change your `cout` line to

```
std::cout << i <<'\n';
```

Run `echo $PS1` in your shell to see what's your prompt.

Your original program prints 1 & then the shell prints the `%` prompt.